# track javascript events when submitting form

Tags: javascript, html

Is it somehow possible to track what JS functions are being processed when submitting a form?

The Chrome dev tool only shows me that there are some JS events, but it doesn't show me the JS code.

Comment: That is unhelpful and unnecessarily critical. We all start somewhere and this forum is meant to be a place where we help each other out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good starting point for stepping through JS code using Chrome dev tools.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/step-code

You can also try downloading Canary, which is Google's browser for developers. It's pre-release, so it can be buggy, but it has much better tools for debugging and developing code.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Put some console.log inside your functions a see the console of Chrome in deck tools as you say

Comment: I can clearly see that JS functions are processed but I can't access the code since it's not on the website's code. the URL i am talking about is : http://www.adidas.de/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-DE-Site/de_DE/Cart-MiniAddProduct